# Sql Three Table Inner Join?

Tags: sql, derby

I'm trying to join 3 tables in a view; here is my situation:

I have a table that contains Sale it Contain Sale Details For per Item
Another Sale Master A All Sale Details of All Item..
And Another Inventory Details

```
String query = "SELECT SALE.ITEM_CODE, SALE.ITEM_NAME, SALE.UNIT, "
            + "SALE.QNTY, SALE.AMOUNT, SALE_MASTER.LONGDATE, SALE_MASTER.BILL_NO, "
            + "SALE_MASTER.LEDGER_CODE, SALE_MASTER.LEDGER_NAME FROM SALE "
              + "INNER JOIN SALE_MASTER"
            + " ON SALE.BILL_NO = SALE_MASTER.BILL_NO SALE"
              + "INNER JOIN INVENTORY ON SALE.ITEM_CODE = INVENTORY.ITEM_CODE"
              + "WHERE  "+CATORINORG+" LIKE '%"+LIKE+"%' "
              + "AND (SALE_MASTER.LONGDATE >= " + From + " AND SALE_MASTER.LONGDATE <= " + To + ")";
```

is it right way.. thanks adv

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: There is error ...in query

Comment: And the error is?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SALE.ITEM_CODE, SALE.ITEM_NAME, SALE.UNIT, "
            + "SALE.QNTY, SALE.AMOUNT, SALE_MASTER.LONGDATE, SALE_MASTER.BILL_NO, "
            + "SALE_MASTER.LEDGER_CODE, SALE_MASTER.LEDGER_NAME FROM SALE "
            + "INNER JOIN SALE_MASTER"
            + " ON SALE.BILL_NO = SALE_MASTER.BILL_NO"
            + " INNER JOIN INVENTORY ON INVENTORY.ITEM_CODE = SALE.ITEM_CODE"
            + " WHERE  "+CATORINORG+" LIKE '%"+LIKE+"%' "
              + "AND (SALE_MASTER.LONGDATE >= " + From + " AND SALE_MASTER.LONGDATE <= " + To + ")
```

its worked for me